# Strange popup - Keyboard stops working and mouse can't be held

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, mouse

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 (I formatted my old Lucid Lynx drive by accident). It's been working great, but every now and then (especially when I leave)   [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21028110/Screenshot%20from%202013-04-20%2001:41:23.png)   pops up, lasts for about 5 seconds, fades away, and a new one appears.
I am using a Dell Studio 1737, a USB HDD for Ubuntu, a USB mouse and a USB keyboard.
It's always plugged in, too, if that helps.

I've googled around, and I've seen a post that lead me to believe that my problem is related to the media hotkeys on the built-in keyboard. They look like [this](http://blog.parts-people.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Studio1735MediaCover.jpg).

It seems that a log-out CAN fix it. Sometimes I have to restart, or shutdown and hard boot.

My friend thinks that it's a driver problem.

I've had good experiences with Ubuntu, left for Windows because of gaming, and I came back because of Steam.  I'm very disappointed in the downgrade from Lucid Lynx to Quantal Quetzal.

I hope someone can make this an upgrade for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue on my new ASUS R500A, with keyboard stopping and the mouse no longer being able to click (moving and hovering still worked) in X. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Fn</kbd> still worked, and I could open a shell from a terminal screen.

I too did stumble into a media key that showed that same "blocked" icon, but I couldn't relate that to the problem. I have no steps to reproduce.

I have the same Ubuntu version running on an older HP laptop for quite some time now and never saw that before.